# How to allow clients from virtual network connect to ubuntu web-server hosted on VirtualBox?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, web-server, http, virtualbox

I have a web-app running on VirtualBox Ubuntu VM. And also I have a virtual network with users which I want to let use this web-app.

Software for virtual network called 'Remobo'. In VM network settings Im choosing bridge connection and then choose adapter matching to VPN software. But while booting Ubuntu prints me 'Waiting for network configuration' 'Waiting another 60 seconds for network configuration' 'Starting without proper network configuration'.

Can someone suggest, how to set-up VBox to recieve http connection from VPN?

Kindly help!

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://paparadit.blogspot.com/2007/08/virtualbox-windows-xp-guest-in-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Your bridge connection isn't offering any IP addresses through DHCP. You may configure the IP address of the guest interface manually.